# Remove encrypted partition from "Kingston Datatraveler Locker+ G3" and make it usable to Linux PC?

Tags: encryption, usb-drive

I have a "Kingston Datatraveler Locker+ G3" lying around. The manual on it explains steps for Windows XP and Windows 7 so it's from that time, I guess. I had some files on it, but couldn't figure out my password and it formatted itself after a few failed attempts.

I would like to make it usable to my Linux PC. In order to do that I'd need to remove the encrypted partition which only has 32 MB to access the main partition which has 16GB.

Is this possible? If so how?

I've done some googling, and this was suggested to format the partition: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX1 bs=1M count=1`. However, I then get the error `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdX1': Read-only file system`.

Unlike Gparted (which sees nothing), the Disk Utility sees both the partition that's accessible without the password, which it's portraying as a CD/DVD Drive and the Drive itself. However, in both cases the `Additional partition options` are all grayed out (except `Edit Mount Options`). This is the case when the device is UNMOUNTED.

Is it possible to make this device usable or can I toss it?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably not (just) encryption that it has implemented, but a drive lock, which can probably be disabled only if you have software that knows how to talk to its firmware and ask it to disable the lock, which should requires the password. So unless you want to bother investigating how you can crack it by flashing a firmware or so, no, you won't be able to use it. (If you recall that you had really sensitive data in it, better don't assume that the data was really encrypted though.)